# Select multiple values from a single underlying values as a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table from which I select multiple values based on two underlying values in the table

```
select (1.2 + ca.MaxReturn),
       (1.0 + ca.MaxReturn),
       (1.0 + ca.MaxReturn * 0.50),
       (1.0 + ca.MaxReturn * 0.25),
       (1.0),
       (ca.BufferLevel + (1.0-ca.BufferLevel)/2.0),
       (ca.BufferLevel + 0.0),
       (ca.BufferLevel - 0.1),
       (ca.BufferLevel - 0.2),
       (ca.BufferLevel - 0.3),
       (0.0)
from  Product.Bren
cross apply (select LowStrike-ProtectionPercentage as BufferLevel,
             ParticipationUpside*UpsideCap MaxReturn) ca
where Id = 1
```

This returns a set of points

```
(No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)
1.350000000000  1.150000000000  1.07500000000000    1.03750000000000    1.0 0.930000000 0.860000    0.760000    0.660000    0.560000    0.0
```

that I want to use to lookup corresponding values in another table

To do that however I need to convert this set of columns into a a single column

i.e.

```
Range
1.3500
1.1500
1.0750
1.0375  
1.0000
0.9300
0.8600
0.7600
0.6600
0.5600
0.0000
```

This looks like I need to pivot the result but I cannot see how to. There are loads of (convert columns to rows answers but none seem to answer what I want.

Comment: You may have to unpivot  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48393/passing-column-names-dynamically-to-unpivot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat the `cross apply`:

```
select v.range
from Product.Bren b cross apply
     (values (b.LowStrike - b.ProtectionPercentage, b.ParticipationUpside * b.UpsideCap
             )
     ) ca(BufferLevel, MaxReturn) cross apply
     (values (1.2 + ca.MaxReturn),
             (1.0 + ca.MaxReturn),
             (1.0 + ca.MaxReturn * 0.50),
             (1.0 + ca.MaxReturn * 0.25),
             (1.0),
             (ca.BufferLevel + (1.0-ca.BufferLevel)/2.0),
             (ca.BufferLevel + 0.0),
             (ca.BufferLevel - 0.1),
             (ca.BufferLevel - 0.2),
             (ca.BufferLevel - 0.3),
             (0.0)
      ) v(range)
where b.Id = 1;
```

Comment: Very smart. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

UNPIVOT looks like it'll do this

```
SELECT Descriptor, Range
FROM 
(

    select (1.2 + ca.MaxReturn) a,
           (1.0 + ca.MaxReturn) b,
           (1.0 + ca.MaxReturn * 0.50) c,
           (1.0 + ca.MaxReturn * 0.25) d,
           (1.0) e,
           (ca.BufferLevel + (1.0-ca.BufferLevel)/2.0) f,
           (ca.BufferLevel + 0.0) g,
           (ca.BufferLevel - 0.1) h,
           (ca.BufferLevel - 0.2) i,
           (ca.BufferLevel - 0.3) j,
           (0.0) k
    from  Product.Bren
    cross apply (select LowStrike-ProtectionPercentage as BufferLevel,
                 ParticipationUpside*UpsideCap MaxReturn) ca
    where Id = 1

) x
UNPIVOT
(
    Range
    FOR Descriptor in (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k)
) AS up
```

You'll get two columns out of this; one with a-k (the aliases I added to your unnamed values) and the other with the value, under the heading "Range" - just in case you still need to track which value was what.

Comment: Thanks, I went with the dual cross apply as it seems, to my eye, to be a bit cleaner